# (Re)define \ref for chapter that includes the part number

Tags: cross-referencing, packages

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow!10}
\usepackage{trace}

% avoid page breaks of \part, \chapter
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\part}{\secdef \@part \@spart}
  \let\@endpart\relax % suppress page break after \part
  \renewcommand{\chapter}{\global \@topnum \z@ \@afterindentfalse \secdef \@chapter \@schapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\thechapter{\roman{part}.\alph{chapter}} % this changes printout in chapter header itself, but not in the ref

Citing part \ref{part:one}, chapter \traceon \ref{chapter:one} \traceoff

\part{part one}\label{part:one}
\chapter{chapter one}\label{chapter:one}

\end{document}
```

... which produces this result:

[image: test.png]

... where the chapter title is printed as "Chapter i.a", and the `\ref` to it also prints "i.a" (as expected due to the redefinition of `\thechapter` as `\roman{part}.\alph{chapter}`)

Here is the thing - I would like to *not* redefine `\thechapter`, that is, I'd like to keep the default "Chapter 1" printout for `\chapter`, and the default "1" for a `\ref` to it. Instead, I would like to define a new command, say `\pcref`, which given a chapter label, would print a "I.A" reference like in the example. How could I do that?

The part of the challenge, I guess, is that the printing of `\ref` (as shown by the trace) reduces to:

```
%...
\@setref #1#2#3->\ifx #1\relax \protect \G@refundefinedtrue \nfss@text {\reset@
font \bfseries ??}\@latex@warning {Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space undef
ined}\else \expandafter #2#1\null \fi 
#1<-\r@chapter:one 
#2<-\@firstoftwo 
#3<-chapter:one
{\ifx}
{false}
{\expandafter}

\r@chapter:one ->{i.a}{1}

\@firstoftwo #1#2->#1
#1<-i.a
#2<-1
{the letter i}

\null ->\hbox {}
{\hbox}
%...
```

... that is, when `\ref` is called, the `\r@chapter:one` command is already set, either to `i.a` or to `1`, depending on `\thechapter`; that is, if there is no information about part number when `\label` is called, no `\ref` redefinition can use it either. So, I guess, the tricky part is doing all this (a new `\pcref` command with old `\thechapter`) without having to redefine `\label`...

Comment: `\global\topnum=\z@` will disable top floats forever. Are you really sure that book is the right class for this job?

Comment: Thanks @egreg - I just took the `book` class because I have that in my original problem, and so I wanted to have `\part` and `\chapter` defined like there; I otherwise suppressed all those page breaks just to have a nice screenshot (showing all on one page) for this question `:)` Cheers!

Comment: Isn't this possible with `cleveref` package?

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer - didn't know about `cleveref` until now, thanks for the mention; cheers!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - just checked `cleveref`; the best I can figure is to use something like `\creflabelformat{chapter}{#2-\thepart-#1-#3}`; unfortunately, this does not change the label format when it is placed with `\label`, but depends on the part where the `\cref` command will be issued; so I guess `cleveref` cannot help much here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not following you into avoiding page breaks, but I'll just show how to do what you seem to want.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@chapter}{\thepart.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\part{Some part title}

\chapter{The chapter title}\label{A}

\section{A section title}\label{B}

``\ref{A}'' is a reference to a chapter, while ``\ref{B}'' is a reference to a section

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: `\p@chapter` is the *prefix* added to the chapter number when a reference to it is requested. Whenever you do

```
\newcounter{foo}
```

LaTeX provides by default an empty `\p@foo` macro.

---

If you want to have different ways for referencing a chapter, you can do like this

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@chapter}{\maybe@part{\thepart.}}
\newcommand{\pcref}[1]{\begingroup\let\maybe@part\@iden\ref{#1}\endgroup}
\protected\def\maybe@part#1{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\part{Some part title}

\chapter{The chapter title}\label{A}

\section{A section title}\label{B}

``\ref{A}'' is a reference to a chapter, while ``\ref{B}'' is a reference to a section
and ``\pcref{A}'' is a reference to a chapter with the part number attached to it.

\end{document}
```

but I'd avoid it. Chapters should be numbered independently of parts, so the problem doesn't present itself to begin with. Having two or more “Chapter 1” is just confusing.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that, @egreg, was not aware about the prefix thing! This does almost what I want, except here `\ref` prints "I.1"; while I wanted to keep the original `\ref`, which prints "1", and have a new command e.g. `\pcref` which would print the "I.1". Is that possible? (ps: if I had page breaks, I would have had 5 pages, which as an image would either be too big or too low resolution for posting; without them, I can show all three sections on the same page, so they are readable in the screenshot posted in OP as well). Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @egreg, that is fantastic - the `\pcref` there is exactly what I wanted! You're right about chapter numbering in general - still, this will be very useful to myself as a reminder while writing (having to refer to chapters in different parts from, say, an introduction). Cheers!