# adding partnumber in a caption

Tags: captions, parts

I have the following question: My work consists of 2 parts. If I include a figure or table in one of the parts, then this table is numbered without the part number, e.g. in the 2nd part the first table is numbered "1.1". But if I want to refer to this table, then the part number is also indicated - it says "see table 2.1.1". How do I make it that the part number is also shown in the caption? Here is my MWE:

...

```
\documentclass[open=any,12pt,oneside,headings=standardclasses,chapterprefix=false,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook} %headsepline obsolete: pointlessnumbers
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage{cleveref}
%%%%%\RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithin=part]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
%%%%%\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\makeatletter
\def\p@chapter{\thepart.}% Präfix für chapter-Labels
\def\p@section{\p@chapter}
\def\p@subsection{\p@section}
\def\p@subsubsection{\p@subsection}
\def\p@figure{\p@chapter}
\def\p@table{\p@chapter}
\makeatother
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,belowskip=4pt,justification=centering]{caption}
%\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf,textfont=it}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
              singlelinecheck = false}
% Dokumentenanfang
\begin{document}
\part{\thispagestyle{empty} {Weg}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\label{ErsterTeil}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
Hi (s. \ref{ma}), have a looak at table \ref{Briefkorr.I}.
\part{\thispagestyle{empty} {Übersetzung}}
\label{ZweiterTeil}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother

\chapter{fff}

ddfdf\label{ma}\\
\begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}[t]{lrr@{.}l}
    Position 1 & DM &  5 & 49\\
    Position 2 & DM & 10 & 95\\
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Korrespondenz}\label{Briefkorr.I}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Added `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}`  to make the  part number  appear in the caption number.

The line `\def\p@chapter{\thepart.}` adds the part number to the chapter label as a *prefix* when a reference to it is requested. See [include the part number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212954/161015).

This table is the first in chapter #1, part #2.

[image: a]

[image: c]

section and chapter numbers are reset after part

```
\documentclass[open=any,12pt,oneside,headings=standardclasses,chapterprefix=false,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook} %headsepline obsolete: pointlessnumbers
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,belowskip=4pt,justification=centering]{caption} 
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false}% Dokumentenanfang

\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  added  

\makeatletter
\def\p@chapter{\thepart.}% Präfix für chapter-Labels
\makeatother    

\begin{document}

  \part{\thispagestyle{empty} {Weg}}
    \label{ErsterTeil}  

    Hi (s.~\ref{ma}), have a look at table~\ref{Briefkorr.I}.

    \part{\thispagestyle{empty} {Übersetzung}}      
    \label{ZweiterTeil}
    
    \chapter{fff}
    
    ddfdf\label{ma}\\
    
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{lrr@{.}l}
            Position 1 & DM &  5 & 49\\
            Position 2 & DM & 10 & 95\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Korrespondenz}\label{Briefkorr.I}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

section and chapter numbers are reset after part

(section and chapter numbers are reset after part)

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem: "Hi (s. 2.1), have a look at table 2.1.1." with your code becomes "Hi (p.2 – ch. 1), have a look at table 2.1.1." - can you say how I get " (s. 2.1)" with your solution.

Comment: An inelegant solution would be \ref{ZweiterTeil}.\ref{ma}, but is there a better soltuion?

Comment: Please see the updated answer

Comment: Is it possible to get table numbers that are independent from part and chapter numbers? For instance, I want that my tables are numbered 1,2,3,... - how can I get this?

Comment: @test Use `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}` instead.

Comment: thanks again, but is there a possibility that the counting passes through  the chapter numbers and is  indepent from it? E.g. when I have 2 tables and there are in Part 1 chapter 2 and 3, it is shown "table 1" and "table 2" (actually, it is shown again "table 1").

Comment: @test  Add `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` to suppress the reset to 1 of the table counter at the start of a chapter